# MySQLSyntaxErrorException near "?" when trying to execute PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a query using a PreparedStatement in Java.

I am getting error number 1064 when I try to execute my query (syntax error).

I have tested this in MySQL query browser with substituted values which works fine.

What's wrong with my code?

Here's the relevant code:

```
String query = "select MemberID, MemberName from members where MemberID = ? or MemberName = ?";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(query);
s.setInt(1, 2);
s.setString(2, "zen");
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(query);
```

Here's the exception I'm getting:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? or MemberName
>   = ?' at line 1

Comment: give more details about the "error" - exceptions in Java have stacktraces

Comment: Just before the executeQuery gets called I see during debugging that the parameters get substituted into the PreparedStatemet, the query becomes "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@6e9770a3: select MemberID, MemberName from members where MemberID = 2 or MemberName = 'zen'"

Comment: Well, you have provided your whole code. And that's the reason noone has answered - it's too long. Isolate the relevant bits and show only them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? or MemberName = ?' at line 1

MySQL doesn't understand the meaning of `?` in the SQL query. It's indeed invalid SQL syntax. So somehow it's not been replaced by `PreparedStatement`. And guess what?

```
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(query);
s.setInt(1, intValue);
s.setString(2, strValue);        
rs = s.executeQuery(query); // Fail!
```

You're overridding the prepared query with the original query! You need to call the argumentless [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) method instead of [`Statement#executeQuery(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

```
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(query);
s.setInt(1, intValue);
s.setString(2, strValue);        
rs = s.executeQuery(); // OK!
```

---

Unrelated to the problem, your code is leaking resources. The DB will run out of them after several hours and your application will crash. To fix this, you need to follow the JDBC idiom of closing `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` in the `finally` block of the `try` block where they're been acquired. Check the [JDBC basic tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) for more detail.

Comment: This is just for a Homework assignment, and also I truncated most of my code, I do have a method that closes all relevant resources.  I tried executeQuery() it works now thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) for `Statement` (the superclass of `PreparedStatement`), the method docs for `executeQuery(String)` and `executeUpdate(String)` say this:

> Note: This method cannot be called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`.

That's what you are doing here: calling `executeQuery(String)` from `Statement` on a `PreparedStatement` object.

Now since the javadocs say that you "cannot" do this, actual behavior you get is unspecified ... and probably JDBC driver dependent.   In this case, it appears that the MySQL driver you are using is interpreting this to mean that you are doing the update as a non-prepared statement, so that the `?` tokens are NOT interpreted as parameter placeholder.  That leads the server-side SQL parser to say "syntax error".

(It would be easier for programmers if a different unchecked exception was thrown by the MySQL driver if you did this; for example `UnsupportedOperationException`.  However, the standard JDBC javadocs don't say what should happen in this situation.  It is up to the vendor what their drivers will do.)

Comment: The JDBC specification does say what should happen: a `SQLException` should be thrown: _"    SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement, the given SQL statement produces anything other than a single ResultSet object, **the method is called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement**"_. However, the MySQL driver only does this 'by accident' in this situation (if the passed statement didn't have a parameter placeholder, it would just work contrary to the specification). Older JDBC specifications (IIRC JDBC 3 and earlier) did not have this req.