# Use java prepared statement with LIKE

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-like

I want to use java prepared statement with LIKE keyword.
I'm trying to match a date string.
Heres my code.

```
String summaryChooser = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT p, CODE_COVERAGE_SUMMARY s WHERE "
                    + " p.product_id = s.product_id AND p.product_id = ? AND s.date LIKE ? "
                    + " ORDER BY s.date DESC LIMIT 1 ";
ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(summaryChooser);
ps.setInt(1, productsResult.getInt("product_id"));
ps.setString(2,  "%" + date + "%");
```

It gives below exception.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND s.date LIKE ?  ORDER BY s.date DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: Its a bit unusual to use LIKE against a DATE column? What datatype is `s.date`

Comment: I bet that your next statement says `ps.executeQuery(summaryChooser)` and that's wrong. It should be just `ps.executeQuery()`. By passing the SQL text to the `Statement.executeQuery(String sql)` method, when you should be calling the `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` method, the JDBC driver ignores the "prepared" parts and tries to execute the SQL directly, as-is. It is a common mistake when using `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Off topic but it is better to use JOIN rather than implicit join using `,`

Comment: Please show the full exception stacktrace and a [mcve] (at minimum include how you execute it).

Comment: And as @Andreas commented on, also post the when executing the query

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Would be nice, but not really needed, because the error is coming from the MySQL server, and the error includes the `?` markers, and the only way that happens is if the SQL wasn't "prepared", which is why I'm willing to bet on my "guess". ;-)

Comment: @Andreas You are probably right, and in that case, this would be a good duplicate: [MySQLSyntaxErrorException near “?” when trying to execute PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131092/mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-near-when-trying-to-execute-preparedstatement)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Here I'm trying to get any record for the date given. s.date field is DateTime.

Comment: @PramodyaMendis If your `date` variable is a complete date, like 2019-03-05, then you can skip the first '%'. As mentioned in previous comments, it is not the query itself that generates the error so please add the the code where you execute the query!

Answer (score -1):

I could make it work by doing this.

```
ps.setString(2, date + "%");
```

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Why would removing the leading wildcard character of a *value*, fix the *syntax error* of the SQL statement?

Comment: In my scenario, I'm not considering anything before the date.

Answer (score -5):

Replace:

```
ps.setString(2,  "%" + date + "%");
```

with:

```
ps.setString(2,  "'" + date + "'");
```

Comment: Why would that help? `'` is not a LIKE wildcard character. Besides, it's unlikely that the *value* of the column starts and ends with apostrophes.