# How to insert String parameters into a PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

How can I create string and then put the String into preparedStatement, or is this same as using Statement ? When I execute the below code, I've got the following message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1".

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 

class firstApp2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");

        String firstName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(firstName);

        firstApp2 test = new firstApp2();

        test.selectByFirstName(firstName);

    }

    public void selectByFirstName(String fn) {
        //System.out.println("test");

        try {
            String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
            String username="root";
            String password="root0216";

            //get a connection (step1)
            Connection myConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);

            String sql = "Select * from students where firstName = ?";

            //create a statement object(step2)
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement=myConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, fn);

            //execute Query (step 3)
            ResultSet myResultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);


            //process the resultset
            while(myResultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("Student full name :" +  myResultSet.getString("firstname") +" "+myResultSet.getString("lastname"));
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Please include the entire error output.

Comment: Very interesting error. Sounds like MySQL read the SQL with qmark still intact but not binded with value which cannot be with this code. That error would occur if you ran SQL without prepared statement. Please re-check your posted code reproduces your claimed error.

Comment: Maybe missing class.forname( com.mysql.jdbc.driver )?

Comment: The problem is the line `preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql)`. Remove the parameter `sql`: it should be `preparedStatement.executeQuery()` instead.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131092/mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-near-when-trying-to-execute-preparedstatement.