# How can i solve JAVA SQL Syntax Error : Error Code 1064

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have this SQL sentence when I create a prepareStatement, I send it the SQL sentence. After this i try to pass a parameter with setString and I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 8
```

The SQL sentence is the following:

```
public static final String SQL_SELECT_RESERVA_BY_CLIENTEDNI =   "SELECT `reserva`.`NUMERO_RESERVA`,\r\n"
                                                                    + "`reserva`.`CLIENTE_DNI`,\r\n"
                                                                    + "`reserva`.`PENSIONES_TIPO_PENSION`,\r\n"
                                                                    + "`reserva`.`FECHA_ENTRADA`,\r\n"
                                                                    + "`reserva`.`FECHA_SALIDA`,\r\n"
                                                                    + "`reserva`.`NUMERO_HUESPEDES`\r\n"
                                                                    + "FROM `hotel`.`reserva`\r\n"
                                                                    + "WHERE CLIENTE_DNI=?;";
```

if we change the question mark as the error suggests, surrounding it with '?', another error happens:

```
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

We think that the error happens when adding a parameter with ps.setString

```
objDatos.Connect();
tabla = objDatos.Consulta(SQL_SELECT_RESERVA_BY_CLIENTEDNI, parametros);
objDatos.Disconnect();
```

```
public ArrayList<itfData> Consulta(String sql, ArrayList<Object>parametros)
     {
            ArrayList<itfData>resultado;
            resultado=new ArrayList <itfData>();
            
            try 
            {
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                if(parametros !=null)
                {
                    this.CompletarParametrosQuery(parametros);
                }
```

```
private void CompletarParametrosQuery(ArrayList<Object> parametros) {
        int cont = 1;
    
        for (Object param : parametros) {
            try {
                if (param instanceof String)
                {
                
                    ps.setString(cont, (String) param);
                    cont++;
                    continue;
                }
```

Comment: try to remove the semicolon, you  don't need a statement separator

Comment: I tried that already, I get the same first error, that tells me to put ''.

Comment: you can try JPA or Criteria.

Comment: SOLVED : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131092/mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-near-when-trying-to-execute-preparedstatement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the error message "near '?' at line 8"

In first place you have to make sure "ps.setString(cont, (String) param);" gets actually executed.
Then, I think the error comes from the way you are trying to execute your query. It seems like you are not using the PreparedStatement. It should be something like this:

```
ps.executeQuery();
```